# Any other sites like darjeleen or flightfox?

Tags: online-resources, flight-search-engines

I want to know if there are any other sites as darjeleen (not operational) and flightfox out there?....

Comment: Flightfox is more or less an interface to contact and pay a travel agent with particular experience in searching airfares, especially for complex trips (multi-city, using miles, mileage runs, etc...). There are, of course, many travel agents out there not on Flightfox, and some also specialize in booking complex air itineraries. Perhaps you could say more about the specific features of these sites that you're looking for?

Comment: Flightfox originally started out as a site for experts to compete in finding the best flights to match the requester's itinerary. I think the OP is maybe looking for similar sites to how Flightfox was.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [chimpando](https://www.chimpando.com/en) and [CleverFlight](https://www.cleverflight.com/). [Future Travel](https://future.travel/) has a hire a helper/expert which is similar but not a contest. [Flystein](https://www.flystein.com/) is another beat my price site.

Comment: CleverFlight no longer exists.  Future Travel, for ten tries of TPE→ICN on 15 Feb 2018 gave "server error" six times and "no flights found" four times.  Flystein & Chimpando may be worth considering, since Azuon and azar are now broken.